# Getting error message "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key "

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

Getting error while running this query in automation, customer key is set to be the Primary key.
Below is the code :

```sql
Select A.ContactKey,
A.AccountId , A.ContactId ,
A.CreatedById  ,
A.Email, A.HasOptedOutOfEmail,
A.hed__Current_Address__c, A.hed__Primary_Household__c, A.hed__Primary_Language__c,
A.hed__Primary_Organization__c, A.IndividualId, A.LastModifiedById, A.LocalAuthority__c,
A.MasterRecordId, A.OwnerId, A.Primary_Academic_Program__c,
A.Primary_Department__c, A.Primary_Educational_Institution__c,
A.Primary_Sports_Organization__c, A.PrimaryAccountGroup__c,
A.PrimaryNetwork__c, A.Region__c, A.ReportsToId, A.ShadowExternalRelationsContact__c,
A.AssistantName, A.AssistantPhone,
A.Biography, A.Birthdate , A.Fax, A.Phone,
A.Description  , 
A.BypassERValidation, 
A.ChosenFullName,
A.Citizenship,
A.CitizenshipStatus,
A.ContactJSON,
A.ConvertedAccountId,
A.ConvertedLeadId,
A.CountryofOrigin,
A.CreatedDate_Contact,
A.CurrentSchool, 
A.Jigsaw ,
A.DateDeceased,     
A.Deceased  , 
A.Department,
A.DietaryRequirements ,
A.Disability ,
A.AddressOverride , 
A.DoNotCall, 
A.DoNotContact  ,
A.DualCitizenship ,
A.EmailBoolean_Contact ,          
A.EmailBouncedDate ,
A.EmailBouncedReason ,
A.EthnicGroup,
A.EthnicOther,
A.Ethnicity , 
A.ExcludefromHouseholdFormalGreeting ,
A.ExcludefromHouseholdInformalGreeting ,
A.ExcludefromHouseholdName ,
A.ExternalRelationsStatus ,
A.HasOptedOutOfFax ,
A.FERPA ,                           
A.Financial_Aid_Applicant ,
A.FirstName ,
A.Former_First_Name ,
A.Former_Last_Name ,
A.Former_Middle_Name ,
A.Name_Contact ,
A.FundraisingInteraction ,
A.Gender ,
A.GenderIdentity ,
A.GlobalUnsubscribe ,
A.HIPAA ,
A.HIPAA_Detail ,
A.HomePhone, 
A.IsEmailBounced ,
A.IsExternalRelationsShadowContact,
A.JigsawContactId ,
A.LastActivityDate ,
A.LastModifiedDate , 
A.LastReferencedDate_Contact , 
A.LastCURequestDate , 
A.LastCUUpdateDate,
A.LastViewedDate_Contact , 
A.MailingCity, A.MailingCountry, 
A.MailingCountryCode,
A.MailingCounty ,
A.MailingGeocodeAccuracy,
A.MailingLatitude,  A.MailingLongitude ,
A.MailingState , A.MailingStateCode , 
A.MailingStreet, A.MailingPostalCode ,
A.Military_Background ,
A.Military_Service ,
A.Mobile_Country_Code ,
A.HasOptedOutOfMobile ,
A.MobilePhone ,
A.Naming_Exclusions ,
A.NoField ,
A.OptIn ,
A.OptOut , 
A.OtherCity ,
A.OtherCountry , A.OtherCountryCode,
A.Other_County ,
A.OtherGeocodeAccuracy, A.OtherLatitude, 
A.OtherLongitude, A.OtherPhone , A.OtherState , 
A.OtherStateCode , A.OtherStreet, A.OtherPostalCode ,
A.PartnershipDescription ,
A.AlternateEmail ,
A.PhoneBoolean_Contact , 
A.PhotoUrl ,
A.Post ,
A.Preferred_Email ,
A.PreferredName ,
A.PreferredPhone ,
A.Primary_Address_Type ,
A.Push_Notifications ,
A.Race ,
A.Religion ,
A.Salutation , 
A.Secondary_Address_Type ,
A.SexualOrientation ,
A.SMS ,
A.Social_Security_Number ,
A.LeadSource ,
A.SystemModstamp_contact ,
A.TeacherReferenceNumber , 
A.Title ,
A.UniversityEmail,
A.Work_Address,
A.WorkEmail ,
A.WorkPhone ,
A.IsDeleted_Contact ,

A.CreatedById_Enrollment,
A.Account_Enrollment ,
A.Affiliation_Enrollment ,
A.Contact_Enrollment ,
A.Program_Plan_Enrollment ,
A.Id_Enrollment ,
A.LastModifiedById_Enrollment ,
A.MainContact_Enrollment ,
A.OwnerId_Enrollment , 
A.RecordTypeId_Enrollment ,
A.School_Enrollment ,
A.IsActive_Enrollment ,
A.Admission_Date_Enrollment ,
A.Application_Submitted_Date_Enrollment ,
A.Class_Standing_Enrollment ,
A.Graduation_Year_Enrollment ,
A.CreatedDate_Enrollment ,
A.Credits_Attempted_Enrollment ,
A.Credits_Earned_Enrollment ,
A.IsDeleted_Enrollment ,
A.Eligible_to_Enroll_Enrollment ,
A.End_Date_Enrollment ,
A.Enrollment_Status_Enrollment ,
A.GPA_Enrollment ,
A.LastModifiedDate_Enrollment ,
A.LastReferencedDate_Enrollment ,
A.LastViewedDate_Enrollment ,
A.ProgrammePicklist_Enrollment ,
A.Programme_Enrollment ,
A.Name_Enrollment ,
A.Start_Date_Enrollment ,
A.StartDateIsToday_Enrollment ,
A.SystemModstamp_Enrollment ,
A.Subject__c ,

B.Id as AffiliationId ,
B.OwnerId as OwnerId_Affiliation , 
B.LastModifiedDate as LastModifiedDate_Affiliation,
B.LastModifiedById as LastModifiedById_Affiliation,
B.CreatedById as CreatedById_Affiliation, 
B.CreatedDate,
B.hed__Account__c  as Account_Affiliation,
B.hed__Affiliation_Type__c as    Affiliation_Type ,
B.hed__Contact__c,    
B.hed__Description__c      as Description_Affiliation  ,
B.hed__EndDate__c        as  EndDate_Affiliation ,
B.hed__Primary__c      as Primary_Affiliation ,       
B.hed__Role__c,
B.hed__StartDate__c    as   StartDate_Affiliation , 
B.hed__Status__c       as Status_Affiliation ,
B.IsDeleted, B.JobRole__c  as   JobRole_Affiliation ,
B.LastReferencedDate, B.LastViewedDate, B.Name, B.POCfor__c  as  POCfor_Affiliation,
B.RecordTypeId, B.SystemModstamp

from [TF_Contact_ProgramEnrollment] A with(nolock)

INNER JOIN [hed__Affiliation__c_Salesforce_1] B with(nolock)  ON A.ContactId= B.hed__Contact__c

Where A.IsActive_Enrollment = 'False' and ( B.hed__Role__c = 'Ambassador' )
```

Comment: If a contact has multiple affiliation records, what is the criteria to determine which of the affiliations to return?

Comment: Also, `with (nolock)` has no effect in SFMC anymore.

Comment: Please update your question to indicate the primary key of the target data extension.

Answer (score 2):

If your criteria is to return only the newest affiliation record along with the contact records, then you can deduplicate the results using the `row_number()` windowing function.  The partition and order-by indicate the criteria for picking one of the duplicates.  The `top 1 with ties` means "give me the record that sorts to the top of the partition."

```sql
Select top 1 with ties
  c.ContactKey
, c.AccountId
, c.ContactId
, c.CreatedById
, c.Email
, c.HasOptedOutOfEmail
, c.hed__Current_Address__c
, c.hed__Primary_Household__c
, c.hed__Primary_Language__c
, c.hed__Primary_Organization__c
, c.IndividualId
, c.LastModifiedById
, c.LocalAuthority__c
, c.MasterRecordId
, c.OwnerId
, c.Primary_Academic_Program__c
, c.Primary_Department__c
, c.Primary_Educational_Institution__c
, c.Primary_Sports_Organization__c
, c.PrimaryAccountGroup__c
, c.PrimaryNetwork__c
, c.Region__c
, c.ReportsToId
, c.ShadowExternalRelationsContact__c
, c.AssistantName
, c.AssistantPhone
, c.Biography
, c.Birthdate
, c.Fax
, c.Phone
, c.Description
, c.BypassERValidation
, c.ChosenFullName
, c.Citizenship
, c.CitizenshipStatus
, c.ContactJSON
, c.ConvertedAccountId
, c.ConvertedLeadId
, c.CountryofOrigin
, c.CreatedDate_Contact
, c.CurrentSchool
, c.Jigsaw
, c.DateDeceased
, c.Deceased
, c.Department
, c.DietaryRequirements
, c.Disability
, c.AddressOverride
, c.DoNotCall
, c.DoNotContact
, c.DualCitizenship
, c.EmailBoolean_Contact
, c.EmailBouncedDate
, c.EmailBouncedReason
, c.EthnicGroup
, c.EthnicOther
, c.Ethnicity
, c.ExcludefromHouseholdFormalGreeting
, c.ExcludefromHouseholdInformalGreeting
, c.ExcludefromHouseholdName
, c.ExternalRelationsStatus
, c.HasOptedOutOfFax
, c.FERPA
, c.Financial_Aid_Applicant
, c.FirstName
, c.Former_First_Name
, c.Former_Last_Name
, c.Former_Middle_Name
, c.Name_Contact
, c.FundraisingInteraction
, c.Gender
, c.GenderIdentity
, c.GlobalUnsubscribe
, c.HIPAA
, c.HIPAA_Detail
, c.HomePhone
, c.IsEmailBounced
, c.IsExternalRelationsShadowContact
, c.JigsawContactId
, c.LastActivityDate
, c.LastModifiedDate
, c.LastReferencedDate_Contact
, c.LastCURequestDate
, c.LastCUUpdateDate
, c.LastViewedDate_Contact
, c.MailingCity
, c.MailingCountry
, c.MailingCountryCode
, c.MailingCounty
, c.MailingGeocodeAccuracy
, c.MailingLatitude
, c.MailingLongitude
, c.MailingState
, c.MailingStateCode
, c.MailingStreet
, c.MailingPostalCode
, c.Military_Background
, c.Military_Service
, c.Mobile_Country_Code
, c.HasOptedOutOfMobile
, c.MobilePhone
, c.Naming_Exclusions
, c.NoField
, c.OptIn
, c.OptOut
, c.OtherCity
, c.OtherCountry
, c.OtherCountryCode
, c.Other_County
, c.OtherGeocodeAccuracy
, c.OtherLatitude
, c.OtherLongitude
, c.OtherPhone
, c.OtherState
, c.OtherStateCode
, c.OtherStreet
, c.OtherPostalCode
, c.PartnershipDescription
, c.AlternateEmail
, c.PhoneBoolean_Contact
, c.PhotoUrl
, c.Post
, c.Preferred_Email
, c.PreferredName
, c.PreferredPhone
, c.Primary_Address_Type
, c.Push_Notifications
, c.Race
, c.Religion
, c.Salutation
, c.Secondary_Address_Type
, c.SexualOrientation
, c.SMS
, c.Social_Security_Number
, c.LeadSource
, c.SystemModstamp_contact
, c.TeacherReferenceNumber
, c.Title
, c.UniversityEmail
, c.Work_Address
, c.WorkEmail
, c.WorkPhone
, c.IsDeleted_Contact
, c.CreatedById_Enrollment
, c.Account_Enrollment
, c.Affiliation_Enrollment
, c.Contact_Enrollment
, c.Program_Plan_Enrollment
, c.Id_Enrollment
, c.LastModifiedById_Enrollment
, c.MainContact_Enrollment
, c.OwnerId_Enrollment
, c.RecordTypeId_Enrollment
, c.School_Enrollment
, c.IsActive_Enrollment
, c.Admission_Date_Enrollment
, c.Application_Submitted_Date_Enrollment
, c.Class_Standing_Enrollment
, c.Graduation_Year_Enrollment
, c.CreatedDate_Enrollment
, c.Credits_Attempted_Enrollment
, c.Credits_Earned_Enrollment
, c.IsDeleted_Enrollment
, c.Eligible_to_Enroll_Enrollment
, c.End_Date_Enrollment
, c.Enrollment_Status_Enrollment
, c.GPA_Enrollment
, c.LastModifiedDate_Enrollment
, c.LastReferencedDate_Enrollment
, c.LastViewedDate_Enrollment
, c.ProgrammePicklist_Enrollment
, c.Programme_Enrollment
, c.Name_Enrollment
, c.Start_Date_Enrollment
, c.StartDateIsToday_Enrollment
, c.SystemModstamp_Enrollment
, c.Subject__c
, aff.Id as AffiliationId
, aff.OwnerId as OwnerId_Affiliation
, aff.LastModifiedDate as LastModifiedDate_Affiliation
, aff.LastModifiedById as LastModifiedById_Affiliation
, aff.CreatedById as CreatedById_Affiliation
, aff.CreatedDate
, aff.hed__Account__c  as Account_Affiliation
, aff.hed__Affiliation_Type__c as    Affiliation_Type
, aff.hed__Contact__c
, aff.hed__Description__c      as Description_Affiliation
, aff.hed__EndDate__c        as  EndDate_Affiliation
, aff.hed__Primary__c      as Primary_Affiliation
, aff.hed__Role__c
, aff.hed__StartDate__c    as   StartDate_Affiliation
, aff.hed__Status__c       as Status_Affiliation
, aff.IsDeleted
, aff.JobRole__c  as   JobRole_Affiliation
, aff.LastReferencedDate
, aff.LastViewedDate
, aff.Name
, aff.POCfor__c  as  POCfor_Affiliation
, aff.RecordTypeId
, aff.SystemModstamp
from [TF_Contact_ProgramEnrollment] c
INNER JOIN [hed__Affiliation__c_Salesforce_1] aff ON c.ContactId = aff.hed__Contact__c
Where c.IsActive_Enrollment = 'False' and ( aff.hed__Role__c = 'Ambassador' )
order by row_number() over (partition by c.contactId order by aff.createdDate desc)
```